# How is your Castle level determined?

Tags: the-mighty-quest-for-epic-loot

In The Mighty Quest for Epic Loot, what determines your castle level and how much does it increase depending on upgrades?

You of course want to maximize the strength of creatures and traps in your castle *without increasing your castle level*, so knowing how it increases is important.

For example, I noticed that placing Roboshieldotron raised my castle level by 2, while removing it did nothing to lower my castle level. I've also noticed that certain research upgrades do not increase my castle level while others do.

Comment: Typing out [the-might-quest-for-epic-loot] or [mighty-quest-for-epic-loot] hits the tag limit, please edit if you can make a better tag given the restrictions.

Comment: Why not simply `mighty-quest-epic-loot` ?  Why `might` without `y` ?

Comment: @Anto spelling mistake, fixed.

Comment: [Yep](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8469/15726), great.

Answer (score 1):

The castle's level only depends on your castle's 'heart' building level.

[image: Castle level based on castle heart]

Comment: I guess this has changed since closed beta? So your castle level is now exactly equal to your castle heart rank?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm still fresh into the game, but it seems like it changed yeah, because I found a lot of threads old of a few months asking the same question.  Yeah, currently it's exactly equal.